# How to know if bus chain has failed or aborted? laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I have my sample code below, the bus is just working fine but I was wondering if it's possible to check if a bus chain has aborted or failed.

I tried assigning a variable but the assignment inside the `catch` function doesn't seem to work. Do we have predefined bus function or variable to determine it? I tried `$bus->failedJobs` but did not work as well.

```
$hasFailed = false;
$bus = Bus::chain($batches)->catch(function (Throwable $e) use ($hasFailed) {
    $hasFailed = true;
})->dispatch();

return $hasFailed ? "failed" : "not";
```

Comment: That will never work, as the catch closure is executed by the job and not the current context.

Comment: There is an approach to actually do this, i will write up an answer when i'm off work.

Answer (score 0):

`$hasFailed` inside the `catch` function won't work because it creates a copy of the variable and won't affect the original value outside the function.

You can use an [inherited reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to the variable by using `&$hasFailed`, which allows you to update the value of the variable in the parent context:

```
$hasFailed = false;

$bus = Bus::chain($batches)
    ->catch(function (Throwable $e) use (&$hasFailed) {
        $hasFailed = true;
    })
    ->dispatch();

return $hasFailed ? "failed" : "not";
```

You can also use the `onQueue` method to dispatch the jobs in the chain to a specific queue and use Laravel Horizon to monitor the queue for failed jobs:

```
$bus = Bus::chain($batches)
    ->onConnection('redis')
    ->onQueue('my-bus-chain')
    ->dispatch();
```